# Send a "ready to call" function in java

Tags: java, function

Is there a way in Java to send a "pointer", per say, to another function so that function can call it when it wants?

At the moment I'm sending all the arguments and using an interface that implements the function that has to be called, as follows:

```
//assumes effectThisPacket has already validated this packet.
public void sendEffectPacket(DatagramSocket s, Packet p, SendReceiveInterface i){ //affect the packet based on effect, then send it (if it's not dropped)
    switch(effect){ //REFACTOR fix this once effect is an enum
    case (1): //drop packet
        //do nothing, the packet disappears
        break;
    case (2): //delay packet
        try {
            Thread.sleep(effectArgs[0]);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        i.sendFromSocket(s, p); //I want to fix this line
        break;
    case (3): //duplicate packet
        break;

    }
}
```

So my question - is there a way to send `i.sendFromSocket(s,p)` (or a different function if I want) to my `sendEffectPacket` function as an argument, so that all I have to do is `call (function)`, not worrying about what the arguments are? Is there a way to pre-construct the entire stack frame that will be generated, send that, and push it onto the stack when I'm ready to?

Comment: Wrap it in a 0 argument lambda.

Comment: `Runnable r = () -> i.sendFromSocket(s,p);`

Comment: Carcigenicate - that makes sense. What do I accept as argument type on the function definition side? shmosel - that doesn't seem safe to do, maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: @BrydonGibson I was suggesting exactly what shmosel wrote. It's a type Runnable. Why would that be unsafe? Runnable in this case is being abused. It has nothing to do with threads.

Comment: Okay, I saw runnable and immediately thought you were creating a new thread. I don't have experience with lambda functions but I agree that solution is the ideal one. Thank you

Comment: @schmosel - revisiting this, it's being called from a inner class that already implements Runnable, so the run method exists. Do I have to (in the constructor of the inner class) generate the lambda expression?

Answer (score 1):

Java 8 comes to the rescue. The technique described is a *callback*, and it was cumbersome to pass results, or call it with a callback.

You will need less classes:

```
public void sendEffectPacket(DatagramSocket s, Packet p,
        BiConsumer<DatagramSocket, Packet> i) {

    i.accept(s, p);
```

And the caller may use lambdas:

```
sendEffectPacket(s, p, (socket, packet) -> {
    System.out.printf("S: %s, P: %s%n", socket, packet);
});
```